# citation in latex in the form of [20-23]

Tags: citing, multiple-citations

How it is possible to create a citation call-out of the form of `[20-23]` in latex?
I write a code `\cite{20,21,22,23}` but it is not correct. could anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us (a) whether you use bibtex or biblatex/biber and (b) which citation management package (if any) you employ (`cite`?, `natbib`?, etc).

Comment: it is not at all clear what your input looks like, `\cite` takes the internal label not a number so something like`\cite{foobar,smithandjones,someone}` which will print as [1,20,35], or [20-22] depending on the document conventions in force.